# Polite way to ask professor's graduate research topics and if any matches an specific area

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, etiquette

currently I'm applying for a specific university I had an exchange program couple years ago, and I asked one specific professor about a recommendation letter, also stated I had the desire to work alongside her as her assistant (being a TA or RA). I'm still waiting for the results (fall 2017), but I would like to ask her which researches she is conducting right now (her focus is software engendering), and if any is with web/mobile development (areas where I have work experience.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to find out what research she is doing, checking out her publications (e.g. in google scholar or scopus) is definitely the first stop (although she might have new projects that are not visible yet). You can also check the lab's website (although often they are not so well updated).

But if you want to ask for a job, then a clear, simple e-mail reminding her of who you are and that you would be interested in working with her if she has any position in your area of expertise, would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Researching a professor's recent publications is a great way to understand their focus, expertise and experience. How many publications have they produced, in the last 5-10 years? Additionally after performing this type of research it is possible to email them directly asking any additional questions you may have about their research focus.